# CancellationTokenSource.Cancel method not changing CancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested property

Tags: c#, .net, cancellationtokensource

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Windows 10 - VS2013

C# .NET 4.5.1

I have a button called testButton and a testButton_Click method that I'm trying to use to do work, but also be able to abort that work. Doing the work in a task is working, and the logic for aborting is being executed (the button turns back to a grey "Run Test"), but the cts.Cancel method doesn't seem to affect the token's IsCancellationRequested flag, or the task has the wrong token, or something...?

```
public System.Threading.Tasks.Task DoWorkAsync(CancellationToken ct = default(CancellationToken))
{
    System.Threading.Tasks.Task T1 = new System.Threading.Tasks.Task(() =>
    {
        try
        {
            var capturedToken = ct;
            // do work here
            for (int i = 0; i < work.Length; i++)
            {
                ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                capturedToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                if (ct.IsCancellationRequested) throw new OperationCanceledException(ct);
                // sleep 1 second
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Caught :) I can do stuff", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        finally
        {
            taskRunning = false;
        }
    }, ct);
    return T1;
}


private async void testButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    CancellationToken ct = cts.Token;
    var task = DoWorkAsync(ct);

    if (!taskRunning)
    {
        Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;
        testButton.BackColor = Color.Red;
        testButton.Text = "ABORT";
        taskRunning = true;
        task.Start();
        await task;

        // Release cursor when setup is complete
        Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;
    }
    else
    {
        cts.Cancel();
        testButton.Text = "Run Test";
        testButton.BackColor = Color.Gray;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you calling `ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();` and `capturedToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();` since `capturedToken == ct`?

Comment: I recommend stepping through `testButton_Click` with the debugger. The only way it would change the button to grey (what you describe to happen) would be if you clicked it a second time, in which case you'll have a different `CancellationTokenSource`, a different `CancellationToken`, and you'll be launching a new task via `DoWorkAsync(ct);`, so it could never cancel the task that was set running when you first click the button.

Comment: On each click a **new** CancellationTokenSource instance is created - you have to store the CTS and cancel that

Comment: John (nice handle) I didn't notice that. Thanks. I'm recreating the cts, ct, and task. When I try to put them in the if (!taskRunning) though, so they don't get recreated the second time, the else sees them as out of scope, which makes sense since the whole click function has ended by the second iteration. How do you recommend I do this? Maybe I should make them global?

Comment: Global worked. If you right this up as an answer I'll happily accept it. Thanks again.